# get wikipedia interlinks doen't give the complete result

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to get the wikipeida intelinks for a specific page, looking into

```
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query
```

I could figure out the query.

For example to get the links in page: Family_of_Barack_Obama:

```
Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_Barack_Obama?oldid=606107993

Dbpeida link: http://dbpedia.org:8890/page/Family_of_Barack_Obama
```

This is my query:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&generator=links&pageids=17775180&redirects
```

But the results are partial, for example it gives the link to the page with title: `145th Ohio Infantry` but not `Associated Press`. I don't know why the result is incomplete? I can't find what is wrong with my query. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **&gpllimit=max** parameter to get all the results.

Try this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&pageids=17775180&gpllimit=max